# Is this sentence too wordy?

Tags: sentence-construction

> One of the reasons that I am applying for this position **is** because
>   your company **is** well known for providing continuous professional
>   training to employees.

I don't think this sentence is wrong but I feel like having two 'is' in one sentence might make the sentence wordy, or is it okay? Thank you!

Comment: You don't need "because" or "to employees."  _One of the reasons I am applying for this position is that your company is well known for providing continuous professional training._

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the repeated "is" is a problem.

Personally, I try to avoid wordy phrases like "One of the reasons that" which don't add much value.

Consider:

> I am applying for this position because your company is well known for providing continuous professional training to employees.

Or even:

> Your company's well-known professional training program for employees is appealing to me.